# Как правильно перевести сайт wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуста, как сделать проверку на наличие плагина, так чтоб если даже его нет - сайт продолжал работать, хоть и с урезанным функционалом. Проверка нужна для плагина Polylang. Или наведите на путь истинный, как правильно делать мультиязычный сайт на wordpress, так чтоб даже работал без плагина в худшем случае но мультиязычность оставалась.

Comment: Почему надо "без плагина"? Без плагина (этого или другого для этих целей) - мультиязычности не будет. Но сайт при этом не поломается и будет работать. В чём собсно проблема*

Comment: проблема заключается в том, чтоб проверить установлен ли плагин, если не установлен то соответственно и мультиязычности не будет, как с этим боротся?

Comment: Непонятно ЗАЧЕМ проверять и С ЧЕМ бороться? Всё просто - есть плагин - его функции (мультиязычность) работают. Нет его/не активирован - не работают. Сайт при этом не ломается.

Comment: например, я использую плагин Polylang, но если он не установлен то мультиязычность не работает, тоесть нужно как-то проверять установлен ли плагин и если не установлен либо говорить юзеру что нужно установить такой-то плагин либо каким-то другим способом делать сайт мультиязычным

Comment: ести ли способы делать сайт мультиязычным без плагинов. Или, если использую плагин, то как сделать проверку на то установлен ли плагин для темы?

Comment: Плагины устанавливаются не для темы, а для сайта. Без плагинов мультиязычности не будет. Никак. Совершенно. Абсолютно. Можно перенести функционал плагинов в тему, но это всё равно что носить трусы поверх штанов.

Comment: Хороший и точный ответ, спасибо. 
Подскажите из свого опыта, как вы лично делаете мультиязычные сайты, з чего начать?

Comment: С разговора о ТЗ и бюджете :)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я задал вопрос для того чтобы узнать варианты и научится это делать а не попросить кого-то сделать это за меня. Это мне нужно для того, чтобы розобратся а не бысто получить ответ и заработать на этом деньги.

Comment: Ну а что не понятно-то? Плагины для мультиязычности для того и существуют, чтобы делать мультиязычные сайты

Comment: Возможно я задал неправильно вопрос, например я нагуглит вот это решение [http://tgmpluginactivation.com/] и сейчас пробую его использовать, чтоб если я сделал перевод с помощью плагина но у юзера, который установил тему но не установил соответсвенные плагины было уведомление о том, что нужно установить то или то для полноценной роботы.

Answer (score 0):

Без плагинов можно - продублировать контент сайта n раз по количеству языков, перевести n-1 дублей, позаботиться о всех переходах между языками, меню, кнопках и т.д. и т.п. Короче, взвалить на себя кучу головняка.

В чем проблема использовать плагин - не понимаю. Да, несколько большая потребность в ресурсах. Но дешевле доплатить за хостинг, чем потратить невообразимое количество времени на вышеперечисленное, получив в результате плохо редактируемый сайт и все равно многократно меньший функционал, чем предоставляет плагин перевода.

Что касается работы сайта без плагина. Не знаю, как Polylang, а сайты, переведенные с помощью [WPML](https://wpml.org/ru/), работают прекрасно и без него - только на основном языке. Переводы недоступны, но хотя бы сайт не падает.

Определить, включен ли плагин WPML и вывести сообщение в header - 5 строк от силы.

Answer (score 0):

Если статические элементы нужно перевести есть отличный jQury плагин [D2S:Lang](https://lang.dev2studio.com)